# Display Classes and Interfaces Separately using Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I'm trying to document a C# project using Doxygen.
With the default configurations, after generating the HTML output, this is what I get for the namespace documentation.

[image: namespace screenshot]

The output adds both Classes and Interfaces to the same list.

I've tried changing some of the configurations, for instance trying to set `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA=YES` to see if something changed, but nothing seems to change.

Do you know if it is possible to generate an output with two different lists, one for classes, other for interfaces, and possibly another for enums?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this manually with pages.

[`DISABLE_INDEX = YES`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_disable_index)

[`GENERATE_TREEVIEW = NO`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_generate_treeview)

Then manually create pages for each of your categories and include the objects you want on each page.

Comment: Thanks Denise, but what I really wanted is for the page generated for the namespace to display the classes and interfaces in two separate lists, like in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web(v=vs.110).aspx). 
In the example above I have the list of classes and interfaces all mixed in the same list.
Your solution only removes the links that allow me to see a list of all namespaces, and a list of all classes.

Comment: I'm not sure Doxygen supports interfaces at low enough of a level to auto generate lists.  You can manually create any list you want on a page.